# Facebook js api publish photo to page, logged in as page

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-page

I am using FB js sdk. I successfully uploaded a photo to a page's feed/photo using code like this :

```
var data = {
  url: "http://some/photo/url.jpg",
  message: "Some message"
}
FB.api('/APP_ID/photos', 'post', data, function(res){console.log(res)});
```

This worked "fine", at least I could get a user message (the current logged one) on the Page's wall, with an attachment, that is the photo. Morehover, it logged `Object {id: "10152003857264383", post_id: "572257189453587_10152003857264383"}` in the console, perfect.

Then I added `access_token: "My_app_access_token_got_from_/me/accounts"` to the post param because I wanted to publish identified as the Page. My post is not on the page, but I get the following answer : `Object {id: "708864122459559"}` (no post_id, that would explained why I don't see any post). I do not see any photo in the Page's photo neither :(.

My page not published (I don't know if it has any side effect).

Do you have any idea why my photo looks like not uploaded ? How can I simply upload a photo to the Page's photo + message on the wall (Like you can do for users, basically) ?

Answer (score 0):

I could finally make it work this way :

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("message", "Some message");
data.append("url", "photo/url");
data.append("access_token", "APP_ACCESS_TOKEN");

$.ajax({
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/PAGE_ID/photos',
  data: data,
  cache: false,
  contentType: false,
  processData: false,
  type: 'POST',
  success: function(data){
     console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Hope it can help !